# iTunes Connect - rejected due to Facebook's "setUrlRequest" method

Tags: ios, facebook, app-store, app-store-connect, facebook-ios-sdk

We have an app, which is using old `Facebook iOS SDK` module. App was rejected due to non-public API in app:

> We found the following non-public API/s in your app:
>
> setUrlRequest:

We're asking tech support to help us finding which module in our app uses method with such name. Tech support said to try this command:

```
strings -a <libraryname.a> | grep -e 'setUrlRequest'
```

and **`YES`**, old `Facebook iOS SDK` module have such method.

So I've tried to use latest (3.5.1) SDK. Built it from sources. Tried to chech it:

```
strings -a libFacebookSDK.a | grep -e 'setUrlRequest'
```

Output:

```
-[FBRequestConnection setUrlRequest:]
setUrlRequest:
setUrlRequest:
setUrlRequest:
strings: for architecture armv7 object: libFacebookSDK.a(FBDialog.o) malformed object (unknown load command 1)
strings: for architecture cputype (12) cpusubtype (11) object: libFacebookSDK.a(FBDialog.o) malformed object (unknown load command 1)
```

So even latest `Facebook iOS SDK` have method, because of which app could be rejected on the way to App Store.

How to solve that issue?
Even more, how other app, which are use `Facebook iOS SDK` could be passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was issue in `Xamarin's MonoTouch` product. Update to version [`6.2.6`](http://docs.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_6/xamarin.ios_6.2#Xamarin.iOS_6.2.6) solved the issue cause:

```
Removal of some non-public Apple selectors (name clashes, old beta selectors and newly blacklisted)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a false positive by the review team. Here's the relevant method: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/FBRequestConnection.m#L266. This isn't a private API, just a method of the FBRequestConnection class defined in the Facebook iOS SDK. It's used as the setter for the urlRequest property defined here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/FBRequestConnection.h#L123. The name just happens to conflict with a text pattern the App Store is probably watching.

Try responding to the review team in iTunes Connect stating these details. They're usually reasonable about things like this if you can provide an explanation.

Comment: Done. Waiting for iTunes team comments.

Comment: Did they ever get back to you?

Comment: Initial response was received. Now we're considering the problem.